# Optimization concern : int to double

Tags: c++, optimization, interpolation

I have these two interpolation methods that I use in some of my programs...

```
__forceinline double InterpolateDouble(double dOldVal, double dOldMin, double dOldMax, double dNewMin, double dNewMax) 
{ 
    return (((dOldVal - dOldMin) * (dNewMax - dNewMin)) / (dOldMax - dOldMin)) + dNewMin; 
}

__forceinline int InterpolateInteger(int nOldVal, int nOldMin, int nOldMax, int nNewMin, int nNewMax) 
{ 
    return (int)InterpolateDouble((double)nOldVal, (double)nOldMin, (double)nOldMax, (double)nNewMin, (double)nNewMax); 
}
```

The method `InterpolateInteger()` simply calls the `InterpolateDouble()` method to maintain some fractional accuracy. Is the conversion from integer to double a concern, and is there any way to get an accurate result using only integers (no casting)?

Comment: Are you asking about the CPU cost of doing the conversion, or are you concerned about something else?

Comment: I'm mostly worried about any truncation involved with all-integer divisions. I'm not sure if the same results will be attained with all integers, so I just converted to double. Performance isn't really an issue but it would be nice to speed it up. I know there's a performance hit with int to float and back... not sure about doubles.

Comment: The casts to `double` in the call to `InterpolateDouble()` are unnecessary; the compiler will make those conversions anyway.  Likewise, the cast to `int` is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a risk of overflow when multiplying before dividing, as your code does here.  You must check the possible values of your inputs, in addition to the possible intermediate calculations of multiplication within the code to determine whether an int type will always be sufficient to contain the calculation.  Truncation *will* happen with integer division, but if you want an integer result, that's expected.
Conversion from int to double is trivial from a CPU perspective, since there's a 0 prepended on the front of the integer before calculation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "there's a 0 prepended on the front of the integer before calculation"?

Comment: Actually, I was confusing a "long" with a double.  You're not gaining anything by casting your integers to floating-point doubles here, except potentially adding some of the inherent floating-point imprecision to your conversion.  You have two integers to start with, and you're only multiplying, subtracting, and dividing them, which you're then casting back to an integer anyway.  There's no reason not to do the calculation as integers.  I mean to write that conversion from an int to a _long_ means only that a 32-bit int is prepended with 0s to make a 64-bit int.

Comment: thanks for the feedback... i'm still quite confused but it's obvious i need to make some overhauls to this method

Answer (score 0):

It's not the conversion from int to double you should worry about. It's the conversion (truncation) back from double to int after the work is done. Consider interpolating [0, 500] to [0, 1]. In that case, once you do the interpolate double, the number will be 1 output for 500 input, and less than one for input 0-499. So 0-499 input will result in 0 output after truncation, and 500 will result in 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after maximum optimization and the interpolation points are fixed, you can use the following integer expression:

```
(dOldVal * dNewDelta + dNewMin * dOldDelta - dOldMin * dNewDelta) / dOldDelta
```

which is of the form `(A * X + B) / C`, where `A`, `B` and `C` are three precomputed integer constants. This will yield exact integer answers.

Alternatively, use `A * X + B` with double precision precomputed coefficients, but the rounding strategy needs to be carefully adjusted.

Yet another possibility is to rescale and round the `A` and `B` coefficients using a power of 2, giving a fast division-less integer formula of the form

```
(A * X + B) >> p
```

(rounding strategy also delicate).